# What are the best practises when adding complex JS plugins to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, javascript

Often, there is a need to use complex JS libraries in Rails. Books and guides suggest that for all js/css/images we should use the asset pipeline

Now, what should be done when my JS needs additional images, css and similar? Everything useful i could find was
http://railsapps.github.com/rails-javascript-include-external.html

If i distribute the resources across the asset pipeline's folders, the plugin usually breaks.
Sticking everything in one folder seems very un-railslike and you probably lose all the benefits from the asset pipeline mechanism

What do you consider to be the best practice in such cases?

**Update:** the matter of fact is, I'm using a third party carousel which requires a lot of resources that are stored in the same dir as the carousel script itself. Since the script is badly coded/documented it's prohibitively difficult to rearange it's resources.

Since i haven't found anything about it on the web, i'll agree with Mike's answer:

**If you must put everything in the same folder, do it somewhere in the vendor/assets dir**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3rd party JS, images and CSS, add them to `vendor/assets` (e.g. 3rd party JS to `vendor/assets/javascripts`, images to `vendor/assets/images` and CSS to `vendor/assets/stylesheets`).

If you *have* to add images in the same folder as the JS code then at least it won't pollute your working directory.

Don't forget you may need to add `//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.` to your `application.js` file if the 3rd party JS files don't get loaded.